# While selecting values in selectOneMenu, values are not getting selected

Tags: primefaces

I use selectOneMenu component. Using Primefaces 5.2. I reduced the body size as zoom="95%". For first time selected an value and once again selecting other value-->value is not getting selected, still the older value is getting displayed.

Xhtml code:

```
<h:body style="zoom:95%;">
    <p:selectOneMenu id="id"  value="#{manageBean.summarySearch.status}"  style="width:180px;">                                            
         <f:selectItem itemLabel="Pending" itemValue="Pending"/>
         <f:selectItem itemLabel="Approved" itemValue="Approved" />
         <f:selectItem itemLabel="Rejected" itemValue="Rejected" />
         <f:selectItem itemLabel="All" itemValue="All" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <p:commandButton value="Search" actionListener="#{manageBean.search}" 
                                        update=":listForm:empDT" />
</h:body>
```

Bean:

```
public void search(){

                summaryList=manageDao.findDetail(summarySearch,new Utill().getId());                    

                if(summaryList.size()==0)
                {
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("editMessage",new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,NO_RECORD_FOUND,""));
                }

            }
```

Comment: This looks like a bean scope related problem. You should show us the relevant code, so we may help you.

Comment: @Zhedar : Question edited.

Comment: But what is the bean scope and import package?

Comment: @Jaqen: Scope is defined as @org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope("session")